# How can I get the functionality I need for both my Navbar and Accordion collapsible to work correctly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just started to teach myself some basic web design and have been trying to use Bootstrap 3.

I've been having issues with my navbar and accordion that seem to be based on the order of my CDN imports. I'm trying to include all imports I need in my navbar/header section so I don't need a >head< section on my other pages.

When I put them in the order I see in every thread I've come across they are in this order.

```
<script src = ...jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = ...maxcdn../3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>
```

With this order my responsive navbar breaks and my hamburger menu no longer works but the accordion collapsible works fine. I understand that bootstrap needs to have jquery loaded first to use some of its features however in order to get my navbar to work I have to switch the two lines above. I believe that this is an issue stemming from the code of my navbar but have not been able to pinpoint the problem.

You can see the broken navbar here:
[Broken Navbar/Hamburger menu](http://www.cannondam.com/testbed/cabin_info.shtml#collapse1)

Here is my Navbar code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <!--Import needed CDN stuff-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href= 
"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
 awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

 <script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
 </script>

  <style>

  body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
        }

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
   float: right;
   display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="topnav" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0" 
                id="myTopnav">
<a href="http://cabins.cannondam.net/" data-toggle="tooltip" 
title="Click here for information on Cannon Dam Cabins" 
class="active">Cabins</a>
                <a href="#Store">Store</a>
                <a href="#FAQ">FAQ</a> <!--FAQ section with Accordian: 
Cabins FAQ, Store FAQ,-->
                <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" 
onclick="myFunction()">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help or tips to improve would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, you don't need media query and JS, the class="navbar-toggle" do it by itself. 
Take a look at this code, maybe it will help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
        <!--Meta-->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!----Style---->

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!----Script---->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style>

  body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }
a{
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
}

.icon-bar{
    background-color:black;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
        }

.topnav a{
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar_home">
                        <div class="topnav navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" id="nav-icon2" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myTopnav">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>                       
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="topnav collapse navbar-collapse" id="myTopnav">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                                <li><a href="http://cabins.cannondam.net/" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click here for information on Cannon Dam Cabins"  class="active">Cabins</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#Store">Store</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the issue has anything to do with the order in which you are calling external resources. It is more likely related to invalid source code or script conflicts.

Looking at the source code on your site I see several problems with your markup. You have two opening `<html>` tags and three opening `<body>` tags. It appears as if you are copying and pasting code snippets without fully understanding how the markup works. Also, you are including the Bootstrap framework, but not fully utilizing it on your page.

First, let's look at how your markup should be structured:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

      <head>
         <!-- Metadata, external resource links, CSS, Javascript, etc. -->
      </head>

       <body>
         <!-- Site Content --> 
       </body>

</html>
```

We begin with a DOCTYPE declaration. Everything else contained in an HTML page should begin with an opening `<html>` tag and end with a closing `</html>` tag. You should never have more than one set of HTML tags on any page.

I am not going to take the time to try and debug your code; it needs to be rewritten. I would start by utilizing Bootstraps built in navigation and eliminating your inline navigation script:

```css
 body, .container-fluid {
 background: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--Import needed CDN stuff-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>


<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="http://cabins.cannondam.net/" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click here for information on Cannon Dam Cabins" class="active">Cabins</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Store">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!--/.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </div>

  <!-- Now We'll Add Your Accordians -->

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="Accordian_Container" class="container">
      <br><br>
      <!-- This is the title of the page, Appears before accordian collapsible panel-->
      <h2 id="PageTitle"><strong>Cabins</strong></h2>
      <!--General Description of Cabins (or subtitle)-->
      <p>Get away from it all at our spacious cedar cabins. All of our cabins can sleep up to six people all on one level. We have special suites available for large groups. Our cabins come fully furnished for your comfort and convenience. Our cabins are
        well suited for weekend getaways, family vacations, family reunions, fishing trips, or company outings.</p>


      <!--Specifing the type of collapsible/panel-->
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

        <!--Beginning code for Collapsible Section 1 (Lakeside Cabin)-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <!-- Adding stylization here affects the panel contents-->
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <!--Assigns relevent information to section header, including the collapse action and  header name-->
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>Lakeside Family Cabin</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <!--Body of collapsible panel 1-->
              <!-- Description of Lakeside Family Cabin -->
              Lakeside Family Cabins are designed to sleep a maximum of 6 people comfortably all on one level. They are situated along our 7 acre private fishing lake. You can fish, play and cook out just feet from the water.
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <!--Video Tour Header-->
              Tour a typical Lakeside Family Cabin:
              <br>

              <!-- Google Drive Embedded Video-->
              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G8LY_ZfvVgFtW0UlvP-bnAaAXGPYTxsQ/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
              </div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <!--Reservations Header-->
              Book your Lakeside Family Cabin now using our online reservastion system or give us a call at (573)-565-4342!
              <br>
              <br>
              <!--Webreserve Calendar-->
              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe id="bookingcalendar" src="https://secure.webreserv.com/services/bookingcalendar.do?businessid=cannondamoperationsincmo&embedded=y&search=0&avgrid=y&css=/assets/css/bookingcalendar-2.0/theme-grey-red.css" style="width: 100%; max-width: 800px; height: 1200px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;"
                frameborder="0"><a href="https://secure.webreserv.com/services/bookingcalendar.do?businessid=cannondamoperationsincmo&embedded=y&search=0&avgrid=y&css=/assets/css/bookingcalendar-2.0/theme-grey-red.css">Make Reservation</a></iframe>
                </div>
              <!--End of Collapisble Section 1-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <!--Beginning code for Collapsible Section 2(3 Room Cabin)-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>Three Room Lakeside Cabin</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <!--Description of Three Room Lakeside Cabin-->
              3 Room Family Cabins have 2 private bedrooms and can sleep up to 6 comfortably.They are situated along our 7 acre private fishing lake. You can fish, play and cook out just feet from the water.
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <!--Video Tour Header-->
              Tour a typical Three Room Lakeside Family Cabin:
              <br>

              <!-- Google Drive Embedded Video-->
              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YzFGqScrcmS88pj_DVBOjNAIOpVFszY1/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
              </div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <!--Reservations Header-->
              Book your Three Room Lakeside Family Cabin now using our online reservastion system or give us a call at (573)-565-4342!
              <br>
              <br>
              <!--Webreserve Calendar-->
              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe id="bookingcalendar" src="https://secure.webreserv.com/services/bookingcalendar.do?businessid=cannondamoperationsincmo&embedded=y&search=0&avgrid=y&css=/assets/css/bookingcalendar-2.0/theme-grey-red.css" style="width: 100%; max-width: 800px; height: 1200px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;"
                frameborder="0"><a href="https://secure.webreserv.com/services/bookingcalendar.do?businessid=cannondamoperationsincmo&embedded=y&search=0&avgrid=y&css=/assets/css/bookingcalendar-2.0/theme-grey-red.css">Make Reservation</a></iframe>
                </div>
              <!--End of Collapsible Section 2-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Beginning code for Collapsible Section 3 (Poolside Cabins)-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>Poolside Family Cabin</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <!--Description of Poolside Family Cabin-->
              Poolside Family Cabins sleep up to 6 guests, feature full spacious kitchens and are next to our indoor pool.
              <!--Video Tour Header-->
              Tour a typical Poolside Family Cabin:
              <br>
              <!-- Google Drive Embedded Video-->
              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ImuBKm38NH528tVdYRr2JaYbxqIKylo/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
              </div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <!--Reservations Header-->
              Book your Poolside Family Cabin today using our online reservastion system or give us a call at (573)-565-4342!
              <br>
              <br>
              <!--Webreserve Calendar-->
              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe id="bookingcalendar" src="https://secure.webreserv.com/services/bookingcalendar.do?businessid=cannondamoperationsincmo&embedded=y&search=0&avgrid=y&css=/assets/css/bookingcalendar-2.0/theme-grey-red.css" style="width: 100%; max-width: 800px; height: 1200px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;"
                frameborder="0"><a href="https://secure.webreserv.com/services/bookingcalendar.do?businessid=cannondamoperationsincmo&embedded=y&search=0&avgrid=y&css=/assets/css/bookingcalendar-2.0/theme-grey-red.css">Make Reservation</a></iframe>
                </div>
                
              <!--End of Collapsible Section 3-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Beginning code for Collapsible Section 4 (Motel Rooms)-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>Motel Room</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <!--Description of Motel Room-->
              Motel Rooms contain 2 queen beds and can accommodate up to 4 guests. Motel rooms do contain a small refrigerator, microwave and coffee maker. Rooms have access to all amenities, including BBQ facilities, indoor pool and private lake.
              <!--Motel Room Slideshow in place of video-->
              <div class="container">
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  </ol>
                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <!--Picture 1-->
                    <div class="item active">
                      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1tc8T5RQiDgXYcwF15q1Chb69gU-69fUN" alt="Motel 1" style="width:100%;">
                    </div>
                    <!--Picture 2-->
                    <div class="item">
                      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=105lHyZjyFc9pxQ_Mztjj0BFJ9ezTH2KK" alt="Playground and Poolside Cabins" style="width:100%;">
                    </div>
                    <!--Picture 3-->
                    <div class="item">
                      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1u9XT6N5tuowChdtl7kxCG095Q4sqA7Jy" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Left and right controls -->
                  <!--Left Control-->
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <!--Right control-->
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">    </span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--End of Collapsible Section 4-->
      </div>
      <!--End of Accordian-->
      <script>
        //When opening panel remove chevron-right, add chevron down
        $('#accordion .panel-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
          $(this).prev().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-right").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
        });

        //When closing panel remove chevron-down, add chevron right

        $('#accordion .panel-collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
          $(this).prev().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
        });
      </script>
    </div>
    <!--End of of accordians container-->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

NOTE: I also enclosed your iframes in responsive divs to keep them from overflowing your content area.